# How to do the count

Tags: oracle-apex

I've a code which will provide me count of records. Addition to this I need to know which level the 'Vinod' is there (whether it is in second level, third level or fourth level'). This information needed in label.

```
Select 'Open' label, count(*) value from DATA
WHERE SECOND_LEVEL = 'vinod' or THIRD_LEVEL = 'vinod' or FOURTH_LEVEL = 'vinod'
```

Answer (score 1):

See whether this helps; `lvl` represents your *second* to *fourth* level.

```
with temp as
  (select 2 lvl, count(*) cnt
     from data
     where second_level = 'vinod'
   union all
   select 3 lvl, count(*) cnt
     from data
     where third_level = 'vinod' 
   union all
   select 4 lvl, count(*) cnt
     from data
     where fourth_level = 'vinod'
  )
select lvl, sum(cnt) sum_cnt
from temp
group by lvl;
```

---

Or this (which might perform better, as the above example queries the same table 3 times):

```
select case when second_level = 'vinod' then 2
            when third_level  = 'vinod' then 3
            when fourth_level = 'vinod' then 4
       end lvl,
       count(*) cnt
from data
where 'vinod' in (second_level, third_level, fourth_level)
group by case when second_level = 'vinod' then 2
              when third_level  = 'vinod' then 3
              when fourth_level = 'vinod' then 4
         end;
```

Comment: Littlefoot, u r always awesome, this gives me exact level. if i want next level, for eg : if Vinod is in 2nd level then I need 3rd level.